# String conditions inside lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression where I need to concatenate strings, however, I only want to display the hyphen if there are values in the subsequent strings that follow. For example, if there is a Wing and a Floor only, I should only display East-3. I tried to insert some string.IsNullOrEmpty() inside the expression but the compiler complains at the Select keyword...

```
param.Patient.PatientGroups.Select(g => g.Wing + "-" + g.Floor + "-" + g.Room + "-" + g.Bed + "-" + g.Table).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: What kind of LINQ provider are you using, LINQ-To-Objects or a database driven provider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx), but you have to convert the fields to an array first:

```
param.Patient.PatientGroups
    .Select( g => String.Join( "-"
                             , (new string[] { g.Wing, g.Floor, g.Room, g.Bed, g.Table })
                               .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                             )
           ).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: +1... Why do you need `.ToArray` call when [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already accept enumerable?

Comment: Just a thought, in case PatientGroups is a big collection:  string result = param.Patient.PatientGroups.Count > 0
    ? param.Patient.PatientGroups
    .Take(1).Select( g => String.Join( "-"
           , (new string[] { g.Wing, g.Floor, g.Room, g.Bed, g.Table })
             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
           )
        ).Single()
    : string.Empty;

Comment: I guess that wouldn't matter too much, since the `Select` will not iterate, but thanks for the thoughts.